# Dynamic scaling in nested layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to have arbitrary `JPanels` containing a `JLabel` sacling dynamically in a container (`JPanel`) with a fixed size. So something like this:

```
__________________________________
| _____________    _____________ |
| | Test Label|    | Test Label| | 
| |___________|    |___________| |
|________________________________|
```

scaling to this

```
__________________________________
| ________   ________   ________ |
| |Tes...|   |Tes...|   |Tes...| | 
| |______|   |______|   |______| |
|________________________________|
```

I tried to use a `BoxLayout` (X-Orientation), setting a maximum size for each contained `JPanel`:

> OuterContainer.Width / NumberOfContainedJPanels

without success. The containers around the labels never fall below a specific width.
Further more using a `GridBagLayout` does not work good, because i want to dynamically add more containers so it wouldn't be a good way to generate the `GridBagLayout` constraints on each adding.

Is there a good solution for this problem? The following is a SSCCE for my problem:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class DynScalingExample extends JFrame {
    public DynScalingExample() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        //---Panel 1
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 32767));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        //---Panel 2
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_1.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_1.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel_1.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label.gridy = 0;
        panel_1.add(label, gbc_label);

        //---Panel 3
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel_2);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_2 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_2.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_2.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_2.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_2.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel_2.setLayout(gbl_panel_2);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_label_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_1.gridy = 0;
        panel_2.add(label_1, gbc_label_1);
    }

}
```

Comment: A `GridLayout` will have that effect (if used right).

Comment: Okay a `GridLayout` works great, but  is there another possibility instead of creating alwaya a new layout when adding new items because of the parameter cols in the constructor: setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0)); setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0)); setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 0, 0)); etc?

Comment: `GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: The second parameter specifies the num of columns, so each time i insert a new item i need an extra column to. That means i have to reconstuct the whole layout each time i add an item. Isn't there abetter solution?

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) are your friend. 0 means add columns as needed.

Comment: Great thanks, it works perfectly. Also thanks for the docs link, i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew Thompson suggested, a `GridLayout` works perfectly for this purpose. As example, see the following:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DynScalingExample extends JFrame {
    public DynScalingExample() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        //---Panel 1
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        //---Panel 2
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_1.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_1.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel_1.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label.gridy = 0;
        panel_1.add(label, gbc_label);

        //---Panel 3
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel_2);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_2 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_2.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_2.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_2.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_2.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel_2.setLayout(gbl_panel_2);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Test label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_label_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_1.gridy = 0;
        panel_2.add(label_1, gbc_label_1);
    }

}
```